# Converting inline ASM to Intrinsic

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, intrinsics

I've been give a task to convert small piece of asm into intrinsic in order to test performance.
I ve never developed any code for either one, but I understand asm and c, and reading up on intrinsic syntax. But I cant find info on how intrinsic is dealing with accessing registers. i found 2 functions:

getReg() and setReg()

getReg() comes with a table of different register tables and their id/number:
-General Integer Registers
-Application Registers
-Control Registers
-Indirect Registers
But none of them seems to correspond to asm registers like rax,rdi and so on.

How can I address registers eg rcx, rdi and so on in intrinsic?
Or in other words how can I convert this:

mov %0, %rcx

to intrinsic equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the point of intrinsics - you don't need to worry about register allocation when using intrinsics (except perhaps in the case of access to special registers in some cases). The general idea is to let the compiler take care of all this kind of low level house-keeping for you. To port raw asm to intrinsics you need to firstly reverse-engineer the asm code, so that you understand what it is meant to do, then re-implement the equivalent code using intrinsics. If you post some of the actual code then you may get more specific suggestions.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was concerned about performance since both intrinsic and asm will be benchmarked to see  how they perform.

Comment: Code written with intrinsics should be as fast as raw asm in general, and in some cases may be faster, since the compiler can often do a better job of instruction scheduling and register allocation than a human.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can use any of these:
GCC: [X86 Built-in Functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html)
MSVC++: [Alphabetical Listing of Intrinsic Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5405h95.aspx)